# How this mixed scipy.sparse / numpy program should be handled

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am currently trying to use numpy as well a scipy in order to handle sparse matrices, but, in the process of evaluating sparsity of a matrix, I had trouble, and I don't know how the following behaviour should be understood:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp

a=sp.csc.csc_matrix(np.ones((3,3)))
a
np.count_nonzero(a)
```

When evaluating a, and non zero count, using the above code, I saw this output in ipython:

> Out[9]:  <3x3 sparse matrix of type ''  with 9
>   stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
>
> Out[10]: 1

I think there is something I don't understand here.
A 3*3 matrix full of 1, should have 9 non-zero term, and this is the answer I get if I use the toarray method from scipy.
I may be using numpy and scipy the wrong way ?

Comment: scipy's sparse matrices are not subclasses of numpy arrays or matrices.  Most numpy functions will not correctly handle a scipy sparse matrix.

Comment: `a.nnz` is the relevant  `sparse` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nonzero count is available as an attribute:

```
In [295]: a=sparse.csr_matrix(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3))
In [296]: a
Out[296]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 8 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [297]: a.nnz
Out[297]: 8
```

As Warren commented, you can't count on `numpy` functions working on `sparse`.  Use `sparse` functions and methods.  Sometimes `numpy` functions are written in a way that invokes the arrays own method, in which the function call might work.  But that is true only on a case by case basis.

In `Ipython` I make heavy use of the `a.<tab>` to get a list of completions (attributes and methods).  I also use the `function??` to look at the code.

In the case of `np.count_nonzero` I see no code - it is compiled, and only works on `np.ndarray` objects.

`np.nonzero(a)` works.  Look at its code, and see that it looks for the array's method: `nonzero = a.nonzero`

The sparse nonzero method code is:

```
def nonzero(self):
    ...
    # convert to COOrdinate format
    A = self.tocoo()
    nz_mask = A.data != 0
    return (A.row[nz_mask],A.col[nz_mask])
```

The `A.data !=0` line is there because it is possible to construct a matrix with 0 data elements, particularly if you use the `coo` `(data,(i,j))` format.  So apart from that caution, the `nnz` attribute gives a reliable count.

Doing `a.<tab>` I also see `a.getnnz` and `a.eleminate_zeros` methods, which may be helpful if you are worried about sneaky zeros.

Sometimes it is useful to work directly with the data attributes of a sparse matrix.  It's safer to access them than to modify them.  But each sparse format has different attributes.  In the `csr` case you can do:

```
In [306]: np.count_nonzero(a.data)
Out[306]: 8
```